# Relationship between sample size and parameter covariance matrix in OLS

Tags: least-squares, sample-size, covariance-matrix

I am dealing with a linear system of equations that I am solving by OLS:

$$
\mathbf{y} = \mathbf{X} \mathbf{p} + \mathbf{e}
$$

Where I have $n$ samples and $k$ parameters ($\mathbf{X}$ is an $n \times k$ matrix)

I would like to work out the relationship between samples size ($n$) and the parameter uncertainties contained within their covariance matrix ($\mathbf{C_p}$).

I have established numerically (by simulating an OLS with different $n$) that the parameter variance decreases ~exponentially with $n$, but am seeking an analytical solution. Extensive googling hasn't got me there, and neither has my sub-par knowledge of linear algebra.

Apologies if this is really basic, and thanks for the help!

Comment: What happens asymptotically depends fundamentally on how you modify $\mathbf X$ as $n$ increases.  What do you propose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a linear model such as:
$$
\mathbf{y} = \mathbf{X} \mathbf{p} + \mathbf{e},
$$
where $\mathbf{X}$ is known and $\mathbf{e}$ is zero mean with covariance $\mathbf{C_e}$ (other than that, the pdf of $\mathbf{e}$ is arbitrary), then according to the Gauss-Markov theorem the Best Unbiased Linear Estimator (BLUE) of $\mathbf{p}$ is 
$$
\hat{\mathbf{p}} = (\mathbf{X}^\top\mathbf{C_e}^{-1}\mathbf{X})^{-1}\mathbf{X}^\top\mathbf{C_e}^{-1}\mathbf{y},
$$
with covariance 
$$
\mathbf{C}_{\hat{\mathbf{p}}} = (\mathbf{X}^\top\mathbf{C_e}^{-1}\mathbf{X})^{-1}.
$$
So if we want to know how the variance of $\hat{\mathbf{p}}$ depends on the sample number, we can make life simple and assume $p$ is a simple scalar, $\mathbf{X} = \mathbf{1}_N$ ($\mathbf{1}_N$ is a column vector of size N) and $\mathbf{C_e} = \sigma^2\mathbf{I}$. This corresponds to the model $$ y_n = p + e_n $$ with $n = 1\dots N$ samples and $e_n$ is zero mean with variance $\sigma^2$. Then the covariance of $\hat{p}$ evaluates to 
$$
\mathbf{C}_{\hat{\mathbf{p}}} = (\frac{1}{\sigma^2}\mathbf{1}_N^\top\mathbf{I}\mathbf{1}_N)^{-1} = \frac{\sigma^2}{N} = \text{var}(\hat{p}).
$$
This can be extended to other models (other $\mathbf{X}$, $\mathbf{p}$ and $\mathbf{C}_{\mathbf{e}}$), but the result holds that the variance decreases as $1/N$. So if your variance decreased exponentially numerically, then something is wrong (assuming that you used the BLUE estimator).

More can be found for example in: Kay, S. M. (1993). Fundamentals of Statistical Signal Processing: Estimation Theory. In Englewood Cliffs NJ Prentice Hall (1st ed.).

Comment: Thanks so much hakanc !

Answer (score 2):

Start off simple. Start with $y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_i + \epsilon_i$. The regression line is given by $E(y_i) = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_{i}$. Suppose you have $n$ observations (i.e. a sample size of $n$). Then for each of the $n$ observations you would have (omitting the expectation operator):

$$
\begin{align}
y_1 &= \beta_0 + \beta_1x_{1}\\
y_2 &= \beta_0 + \beta_1x_{2}\\
\vdots \\
y_n &= \beta_0 + \beta_1x_{n}\\
\end{align}
$$

and in matrix form you have

$$\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
    y_1 \\
    y_2 \\
    \vdots\\
    y_n 
\end{bmatrix}}_{Y} = \underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & x_1 \\
    1 &  x_2 \\
    \vdots\\
     1 & x_n 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    \beta_1  \\
    \beta_2 
\end{bmatrix}}_{X\beta}.$$

The covariance is given by $\sigma^2(X^TX)^{-1}$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thank you! This is so obvious and everything makes sense now. Giving the answer to the other person though, as it's more complete... sorry!